# Install dotnet sdk `6.0.400-preview` without the installer of Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, installation, sdk

How can I install any dotnet sdk `6.0.400-preview` without the installer of Visual Studio?

Currently on my mac I have `6.0.400-preview.22330.6` installed. I installed that with the installer of Visual Studio Preview.

The installer for the latest non-preview version `6.0.302` can be downloaded from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0. But not for `6.0.400-preview`.

I'm looking forward to solutions for macOS, Windows or Linux - does not matter which operating system.

Comment: The latest version currently available for download from the official website is [.NET SDK 6.0.302](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0). If you want to use 6.0.400-preview, you should only be able to download the [VS2022 preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview)

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT is there no way to install 6.0.400-preview without Visual Studio?

Comment: It seems so, it's only available in vs2022 preview as it's not officially released yet.